# How to build gtest static library from my project CMakeLists.txt?

Tags: c++, cmake, googletest

I have a main **project** with a subproject **tests**.
In **project/CMakeLists.txt** I added

```
add_subdirectory(tests)
```

In **project/tests/CMakeLists.txt** I plug in "pre-compiled" gtest library (from Ubuntu repository). I *cd* to /usr/src/gtest and compile two *.a files into system lib directory.
And it works fine, until issue scribed in [google test FAQ](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/FAQ.md#why-is-it-not-recommended-to-install-a-pre-compiled-copy-of-google-test-for-example-into-usrlocal) appeared.

How to build gtest static library files from **project/tests/CMakeLists.txt** and how to use this new *.a files instead of system ones?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finaly I find out how to rebuild static **libgtest.a** without adding googletest as a subproject.

Using info from [this](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/README.md) link and from the bottom of [this](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/target_link_libraries.html) link.

Interesting part of my project/tests/CMakeLists.txt:

```
.....
# Locate GTest
#find_package(GTest REQUIRED)
#include_directories(SYSTEM ${GTEST_INCLUDE_DIRS})
set(GTEST_SRC /usr/src/gtest/src/gtest-all.cc)
include_directories(SYSTEM /usr/src/gtest # <-- path to non-header files from gtest-all.cc
                           /usr/include)  # <-- path to gtest headers

add_library(gtest STATIC ${GTEST_SRC})    # <-- make static library target before main project executable
target_link_libraries(gtest ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT})

# Link runTests with what we want to test and the GTest and pthread library
add_executable(tests ${SRC})
target_link_libraries(tests ${Boost_LIBRARIES} ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT} gtest) # <-- finaly link this library as others
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm starting from beginning.
First, download the googletest source code from

> https://github.com/google/googletest

When we download this ZIP-files, we get the googletest and googlemock project, but here I will only use the googletest folder. I unpack the ZIP and copy the googletest folder to my project, e.g.:

```
/home/name/myProject/
```

The content from this folder could look like the following:

```
- CMakeLists.txt
- googletest /
- main.cpp
```

In the CMakeList file I can add gtest as a subdir and link my executable against it. I build a minimal example:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6.4)
project(MyProject)

enable_testing()
add_subdirectory( googletest )

# this sets the output dir to /bin
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)

include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/googletest/include)
add_executable(myExe main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(myExe gtest_main gtest)
```

The last three lines set the include path to googletest, add the executable and link the exe against gtest.
After downloading gtest and creating the cmake structure, you can build you program:

```
$ mkdir bin
$ cd bin
$ cmake ..
$ make
```

and call the exe:

```
$ ./myExe
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: This way is useful too but I wish to avoid making googletest subproject.